# Find out if point is touching line

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces

So, let's assume I have a line that made up of point one (x1, y1) and point two (x2, y2). Then I have a third point somewhere in two dimensional space (x3, y3). I would like to find out if this point is 'touching' the line.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF0UW.png)

How could I go about doing this? I guess I could go about fiding whether the point is between the line's X and Y values, then if it aligns with the angle of the line. Not sure if that is at all a good way to approach the problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ we can find the equation of the line passing through them using point slope form. The equation is given by $y-y_1 = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} (x-x_1)$. Now all points which lie on this line must satisfy this equation. That is, you can plug in $y_3$ for y and $x_3$ for x and see if the equation holds true for that point (to be more concrete, see if you can reduce the equation using algebra to 0=0).

Comment: Nitpick: $y - y_1 = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}(x - x_1)$ is called two-point form whereas $y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)$ is called point-slope form.

Answer (score 0):

Plug the point into the equation for the line. If the left-hand side equals the right-hand side, then the point lies on the line.

For example consider the line $y = x+1$. Now suppose you want to know if $(1,3)$ lies on this line. Well, $3 \neq 1+1$ so the point does not lie on the line, but $(1,2)$ does since $2 = 1+1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of collinearity - the third point will lie on the line between the first two points if we can write $(x_3,y_3)=(1-t)(x_1,y_1)+t(x_2,y_2)$ for some $t\in[0,1]$, and on an extension of that line if the same equation holds for some $t\notin[0,1]$.

A quick way to check this would be to compute $(x_2,y_2)-(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_3,y_3)-(x_1,y_1)$, and see whether these are scalar multiples of one another. This is true $\iff$ they all lie on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to treat the points as vectors, find the difference between two pairs of vectors, then check if the difference vectors are scalar multiples of each other.